# working with NSPredicates and NSFetchrequests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to get the url of the first picture of an album. I am getting my data from a json webservice. This webservice looks like this.

```
  "albums": [

        {
            "name": "Club Brugge - KRC Genk",
            "date": "08.10.2012",
            "pic_album_id"  : 1
            "pictures": [
                {
                    "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg",
"picture_id" : 1
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/e8e10c0664eb0533a0534ed69891b165.jpg"
"picture_id" : 2
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/750b55a87b8eae33b8f3278add9bec44.jpg"
"picture_id" : 3
                },
                {
                    "url": "http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/5867e1dedd00d08d830fd7f098a0b747.jpg"
"picture_id" : 4
                }
```

I am trying to get only the first URL. I am trying to get this with the following function.

```
- (NSString *)getFirstPictureOfAlbumId: (int)AlbumId
{

    NSString *picture_Url = [[NSString alloc]init];
      NSLog(@"here1");
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
      NSLog(@"here2");
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(picture_id == 1) AND (pic_album_id == %@)",AlbumId];
      NSLog(@"here3");
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Picture" inManagedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext]];
      NSLog(@"here4");
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
      NSLog(@"here5");
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        //handle errors
    }
    NSLog(@"picture url is: %@",[results valueForKey:@"url"]);
    picture_Url = [results valueForKey@"url"];
    return picture_Url;
}
```

My logs only reaches to "here2" So I think there is something wrong with my predicate. Another problem I have is to store the url of the first picture.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is what I do in my tableview

```
 NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self getFirstPictureOfAlbumId:indexPath.row+1]]];
    NSLog(@"indexpatch is: %d",indexPath.row+1);
    NSLog(@"first picture is: %@",[self getFirstPictureOfAlbumId:indexPath.row+1]);
```

And then it logs it like this.

```
012-10-09 13:17:58.140 RacingGenk[6069:c07] album id is: 1
2012-10-09 13:17:58.311 RacingGenk[6069:c07] indexpatch is: 1
2012-10-09 13:17:58.311 RacingGenk[6069:c07] album id is: 1
2012-10-09 13:17:58.313 RacingGenk[6069:c07] first picture is: http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg
2012-10-09 13:17:58.314 RacingGenk[6069:c07] album id is: 2
2012-10-09 13:17:58.445 RacingGenk[6069:c07] indexpatch is: 2
2012-10-09 13:17:58.445 RacingGenk[6069:c07] album id is: 2
2012-10-09 13:17:58.446 RacingGenk[6069:c07] first picture is: http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg
2012-10-09 13:17:58.447 RacingGenk[6069:c07] album id is: 3
2012-10-09 13:17:58.577 RacingGenk[6069:c07] indexpatch is: 3
2012-10-09 13:17:58.577 RacingGenk[6069:c07] album id is: 3
2012-10-09 13:17:58.578 RacingGenk[6069:c07] first picture is: http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg
```

**EDIT2**

LOG

```
RacingGenk[6605:c07] picture_id=1, album_id=1, url=http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg
2012-10-09 13:57:40.361 RacingGenk[6605:c07] picture_id=1, album_id=2, url=http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg
2012-10-09 13:57:40.525 RacingGenk[6605:c07] picture_id=1, album_id=3, url=http://www.krcgenk.be/images/gallery/album_199/800X600/1a06dc0e405fd0219e3d327f1eec7fbf.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(picture_id == 1) AND (pic_album_id == %@)", AlbumId];
```

you use "%@" as format specifier (which is for *objects*), but an *int* argument `AlbumId`.

If the "pic_album_id" attribute is stored as `NSNumber` in your Core Data model, then the predicate must be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(picture_id == 1) AND (pic_album_id == %@)",
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:AlbumId]];
```

(*Note:* In Objective C, it is very common to let variable names start with a lower case letter, i.e. `albumId` instead of  `AlbumId`. Using that convention makes your code easier to read for others in this forum.)

**EDIT:** To get the first picture that is in an album with given `albumId`, the following predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(picture_id == 1) AND (album.pic_album_id == %@)",
   [NSNumber numberWithInt:albumId]];
```

This code assumes that you have an inverse relationship *album* from the *Picture* entitiy to the *Album* entity (inverse relationship to *pictures*).

Even if there is only one result, it is stored in an array:

```
NSArray *results = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    // handle errors
} else if (results.count == 0) {
    // nothing found
} else {
    Picture *picture = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"picture_id=%@, album_id=%@, url=%@", picture.picture_id, picture.album.pic_album_id, picture.url);
    pictureUrl = [picture url];
}
```

Comment: Oké thank you, but I have another problem. It is still giving the same picture url back. I've edited my question.

Comment: Strange, it is still giving back the same image.

Comment: @StefGeelen: What do you mean by "giving back the same image"? What result do you get from the fetch request? What result do you expect?

Comment: @StefGeelen: I have added an `NSLog` statement to my answer. Can you add that to your code and show the result? Perhaps it helps to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @StefGeelen: The log output clearly shows that the fetch request gives *correct results*, but *all pictures have the same URL*. Perhaps you have a problem where you store the data from the web service into Core Data. You should first check that the JSON data from the web service is correct and then check if it is stored into Core Data correctly. If there is a problem in that area, you should ask a new question, because that would be unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NSPredicate before and maybe you could use this

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == 1"];
```

Use the EXACT variable names for NSPredicate as what is returned from your webservice.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, I don't think the problem are my names